# Concatenate three inputs of different dimensions in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, keras-layer

I have two inputs of same size and then applied word embeddings of vector size 128 and then reshape it giving both inputs shape of (none,1,128), another input which is context has dimension (none,1,18), I want to concatenate these three inputs and then feed the combined output to an LSTM layer. But I am unable to concatenate the inputs as dimensions are different with this error:

*A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 1, 128), (None, 1, 128), (None, 1, 18)]*

```
   combined= Concatenate(axis=-2)([input_1,input_2, input_3])
```

The two inputs of shape (none,1,128) are word embeddings while third input of shape(none,1,18) is one hot encoding of some categorial variable.

Does anyone know how to do concatenate this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

concatenate them on the last dimension

```
input_1 = Input((1,128))
input_2 = Input((1,128))
input_3 = Input((1,18))

combined = Concatenate(axis=-1)([input_1,input_2, input_3])
```

this produces a combined tensor of shape (batch_dim, 1, 274)

Comment: and what If I want to concatenate on axis=-2, then what could be the best solution?

Comment: you can't because 128 != 18. all the axes (expect the concatenation one) must be equal. if your scope is fed the combined output to an LSTM layer Concatenate(axis=-1) is what you need